# Window "load" addEventListener doesn't fire

Tags: javascript

I'm curious about one thing. I'm loading the script in `<head>` following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var domain = "http://example.com";
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.onload = function() {
    Lib.init(domain);
    Lib.watchAll();
  };
  script.src = domain + "/dist/sdk.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

and I would like to ask one thing - I've got `window.addEventListener("load", function() {console.log("loaded");});` inside `Lib.watchAll();` but it never gets invoked. Could someone explain me why?

Comment: You may not need `addEventListener` inside `watchAll`. Just put a `log` statement and check

Comment: Well your script is set to be async and the code to setup the listener isnt run until after that and the onload event fires. By this time the `window`'s own `onload` event has likely already fired

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks! So am I be sure that window is already loaded in `watchAll()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 flaws in your javascript.

No.1 When your elements `onload` gets fired, the window has most likely already been loaded so you won't catch the event.

No.2 You cannot add an `onload` listener to a dynamically created element. It will never fire. What you want to do is use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or listen to the [`DOMNodeInserted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) event (keep in mind, that the latter is deprecated and therefor discouraged).

Comment: Is it possible to somehow modify the code to be sure that window is loaded when `Lib.watchAll` method is called?

Comment: No.1: Call your code on `window.onload`.
No.2: Schedule your code on `window.onload` (using `setTimeout(..)`, `window.requestIdleCallback(..)`, etc.
No.3: On window load save true in a variable that you can access (`let loaded = true;`).